# case when condition with group by query with mysql

Tags: mysql

Below is my mysql query :

```
SELECT u.id,
   CASE WHEN (p.PaymentType = "FreeCredit") THEN SUM(p.CreditedAmount) ELSE 0 END AS freecredit ,
   CASE WHEN (p.PaymentType = "Online") THEN SUM(p.CreditedAmount) ELSE 0 END AS onlinepayment,
    CASE WHEN (p.PaymentType = "Cash") THEN SUM(p.CreditedAmount) ELSE 0 END AS Cash
FROM users as u

LEFT JOIN payment as p on u.id = p.UserId AND p.PaymentSucc = "Yes" 

WHERE  

`u`.`UserType` = 'User' 

  GROUP BY p.UserId

ORDER BY u.id DESC;
```

Required result : in payment table I have 3 payment type in result I required to show sum for particular payment type for single user like below,

```
userid= 1974
PaymentType =  FreeCredit,CreditedAmount= 120
PaymentType = Online ,CreditedAmount== 140
PaymentType = cash ,CreditedAmount==100

PaymentType =  FreeCredit,CreditedAmount== 100
PaymentType = Online ,CreditedAmount== 120
PaymentType = cash ,CreditedAmount==170
```

in required result it should be as below,

```
id      freecredit  onlinepayment   Cash
1972    220         260             270
```

from my query ,I am not able to get above result ,please can any person help me to resolve my this mysql query issue:

I will appreciate best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question (y)

So,

Here's table user:

```
mysql> select * from user;
+----+-----------+
| id | user_type |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | krish     |
|  2 | bala      |
+----+-----------+
```

Here's table payment:

```
mysql> select * from payment;
+------+-------------+----------------+
| id   | PaymentType | CreditedAmount |
+------+-------------+----------------+
|    1 | FreeCredit  |            120 |
|    1 | Online      |            140 |
|    1 | cash        |            100 |
|    1 | FreeCredit  |            100 |
|    1 | Online      |            120 |
|    1 | cash        |            170 |
|    2 | FreeCredit  |            500 |
|    2 | Online      |            450 |
|    2 | FreeCredit  |            230 |
+------+-------------+----------------+
```

The goal is to have - for each ID -  the sum of 'FreeCredit' / 'Online' / 'cash'

```
select u.id, sum(case when PaymentType = "FreeCredit" then     
CreditedAmount else 0 end) as freeamnt, sum(case when PaymentType = 
'Online' then CreditedAmount else 0 end) as Online, sum(case when 
PaymentType = 'cash' then Creditedamount else 0 end) as cash from user 
as u left join payment as p on u.id=p.id group by p.id order by u.id 
desc;

+----+----------+--------+------+
| id | freeamnt | Online | cash |
+----+----------+--------+------+
|  3 |        0 |      0 |    0 |
|  2 |      730 |    450 |    0 |
|  1 |      220 |    260 |  270 |
+----+----------+--------+------+
3 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Note:

1. I simulated a sample based upon your examples
2. The query is based on my sample and it won't have all the 'where' conditions you have given

Comment: I have checked this query in my code and it is working,thanks

Comment: So.. it did help you... Glad to hear.. I spent more than one hour trying to find a solution for this.... and since I didn't get any response.. thought it was not good for you...